# Periodic JobScheduler doesn't respect constraints

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

Using the [`JobScheduler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html), I set up a simple [`JobService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html) as follows:

```
@TargetApi(21)
public class SimpleJobService extends JobService {
    private static final String TAG = "SimpleJobService";

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        if (jobParameters.isOverrideDeadlineExpired()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "This shouldn't happen");
            Toast.makeText(this, "This shouldn't happen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        jobFinished(jobParameters, false);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I then setup the `JobService` to be periodic (every minute) and require unmetered network and charging:

```
    ComponentName jobServiceComponent = new ComponentName(this, SimpleJobService.class);

    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(2, jobServiceComponent);
    builder.setPersisted(true);
    builder.setPeriodic(60000);
    builder.setRequiresCharging(true);

    builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED);
    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

The `onStartJob` of my `SimpleJobService` is being called regardless of whether my device is charging or if it's on an unmetered network.

The documentation for [`setPeriodic(long)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setPeriodic(long)) says it can't be used in conjunction with [`setOverrideDeadline(long)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setOverrideDeadline(long)) (and I'm not anyway), but I'm surprised that `jobParameters.isOverrideDeadlineExpired()` in `onStartJob` is ever `true` with this setup.

Am I missing something here?

This looks like an Android bug to me, but I'm surprised I couldn't find other people reporting this issue.

This behaviour was observed on Android 6.0.1

Answer (score 3):

A periodic job has an implicit deadline of the end of the period as seen in [the source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/controllers/JobStatus.java#L91).

Just like explicitly setting a deadline, this gives you an opportunity to decide on how best to handle extended periods of time (you'll note there is a minimum interval, queryable on Android 7.0+ devices with [getMinPeriodMillis()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.html#getMinPeriodMillis())) when your conditions are not met. For example, if your constraints are hard requirements, you can call `jobFinished(jobParameters, false)` to wait for the next periodic end point or the conditions to be true.

Comment: Good spot. If that's intended behaviour, I certainly think it warrants a comment in the API docs like the one on `setOverrideDeadline()`as the unwary could easily be tripped up by it - e.g. transfer huge volume of data on metered network.

Comment: Whilst this description seems a perfectly reasonable way to implement the JobScheduler, I think there must be a bug here somewhere. Further testing shows that if I call `jobFinished(jobParameters, true)` from `onStartJob` the job is then never rescheduled until the other criteria for the job are true, whereas if it was deliberately using the period as some sort of deadline I'd expect it to then apply the backoff criteria and reschedule the job as I asked it to, continuing to ignore the other criteria. This behaviour seems inconsistent to me!

Comment: Yep, backed off jobs don't have override deadlines associated with them and this includes the implicit override deadline set by periodic jobs.